# Cannot use Bootstrap collapse functionality with Angular routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

**UPDATE #2:** I've implemented a button and UI Bootstrap and got the menu functioning without Angular Routing taking over, however, I can't get the menu to collapse after selecting a menu item and rerouting.

**UPDATE:** As per the suggestion, I've updated the above listener to this (to no effect):

```
$('a:not([data-toggle="collapse"])').click(function (e) {
    var url = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href') || '#';
    if (!(url.charAt(0) == '#')) {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
});
```

All of the Angular code for this app seems to be in js/compiled.min.js - if something is wrong, surely it'd start here, right?

I have inherited some work from a previous developer that has some funky code which is causing me a bit of a headache. If you visit http://www.executionists.com/#/ in Chrome and change the viewport to a mobile device, you'll see that the menu doesn't work as it does when it's in a larger viewport.

When you click the menu button Angular tries to route the page which of course results in a 404. I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's trying to route and how to prevent it. Things that I've tried.

Using UI Bootstrap in the manner listed here (under Collapse section): http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

One thing to note is that I had to put the following fix in place to fix another bug where angular routing was not allowing for browser history to function. A common problem, I have discovered. When I put the fix in place, routing and history function as desired for the entire site, however, I am suspicious of this being the cause of my mobile-friendly collapsible menu bug. The fix:

```
// This is required for links to work properly with the browser history
$('[ng-app]').on('click', 'a', function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

I don't know what to do about this or even how to best diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting all links with that listener, perhaps be more specific:

```
$('a:not([data-toggle="collapse"])').click(function (e) {
    var url = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href') || '#';
    if (!(url.charAt(0) == '#')) {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
});
```

Comment: Oddly enough, that has no effect at all, that I can see. The normal links function as they should while the menu toggle button still tries to route via Angular.